# The future and PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova, storage, offlineapps

I'm working in a project on PhoneGap, HTML5, JQuery, WorkOnLine and OffLine, and I want to know if I PhoneGAP is a good option for develop software for a company, and the main is if Storage API (webSQL) provided with PHONEGAP will be maintained for long time o we must to change in the future our application and use other API/System to have a SQL storage system.
This question is due to I want a Storage System that can be powerfull and reliable, and compatible with CrossPlatform like PhoneGAP and in the future my apps being compatible with new storage API's.

Options?:
API Storage PhoneGAP,
YDN-DB,
PersistenceJS, 
...

Which is the best when I want an app for the future (a few years)?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) for data operations. It's brand new but seems very useful.

Comment: But have remote sync o something like it?